# Второе окно Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как правильно открыть второе окно приложения в Tkinter?

Comment: Выше плохой вариант! Правильно открывать окно через `new_win = tkinter.Toplevel(root)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создание второго окна в Tkinter не отличается ни чем принципиально от создания первого. Так же необходимо создать новый экземпляр приложения. Ниже пример создания приложения создающего несколько окон:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button


class MainApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwarg)

        label = Label(self, text='First Window')
        button = Button(self, text='Open Window', command=self.new_window)

        label.pack()
        button.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        Window().mainloop()


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwarg)

        label = Label(self, text='Second Window')
        label.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().mainloop()
```

Comment: Тоже рабочий вариант :)

Comment: Это плохой вариант, например в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/929706/1365) видно, что такой вариант вызывает глюки при работе с переменными, привязанными к виджетам.

Answer (score 3):

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    # Добавление элементов в window
    ...

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А как тогда передать данные можно из дочернего окна в основное?

Comment: Хранить ссылку на дочернее окно и основное, по какому-то событию (например, клик кнопки) брать из дочернего окна данные и вставлять в основное

Answer (score 1):

Лучший вариант - отдельный `py` файл.
Создаем в папке с этим скриптом (будем его называть `main.py`). Его назовем `new_window.py`. В нем создаем окно:

```
import tkinter
# дальше импортируй все что нужно
root = Tk()
# вставляем код
root.mainloop()
```

Сохраняем и переходим к `main.py`. В нем пишем это:

```
# это пишем вместе со всеми импортами
import os
# дальше пишем в моменте когда нужно вызвать окно
os.system('python new_window.py')
```

Также, если вам нужно убить предыдущее окно, то используйте это:

```
# это пишем со всеми импортами
import sys
# пишем после "os.system"
sys.exit(0)
```

Можно использовать функции `create_window` и `kill_newwin`:

```
def create_window():
    os.system('python new_window.py')

def kill_newwin():
    os.system('python new_window.py')
    sys.exit(0)

root = tk.Tk()
a = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
a.pack()
b = tk.Button(root, text='Create new window and close current', command=kill_newwin)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```