# Не изменяется поле IntVar() в классе

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-faq

В общем, есть класс(в конструкторе добавляется поле iw StringVar и ir IntVar)
далее эти поля привязываются к элементам из ткинтера, ir допустим привязывается к радиобаттон. И вот, когда выполняется метод show_message поле ir всегда равен 0, скорее всего и iw не меняется. В чем причина?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

class TranWin:
    """description of class"""
    def __init__(self):  
        r = Tk()
        r.title("Translate")
        r.geometry("400x300")
        poetry = "Binary number"
        label2 = Label(r, text=poetry, justify=LEFT)
        label2.place(relx=.3, rely=.1)

        self.iw = StringVar()

        message_entry = Entry(r, textvariable=self.iw)
        message_entry.place(relx=.7, rely=.13, anchor="c")
        message_button = Button(r, text="Translate", command=self.show_message)
        message_button.place(relx=.7, rely=.3, anchor="c")

        self.ir = IntVar()

        Radiobutton(r, text='16', value=1, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=3, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(r, text='10', value=2, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=4, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(r, text='8', value=3, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=5, sticky=W) 
        r.mainloop()

    def show_message(self):
        l=self.ir.get()
        if l==1:
            messagebox.showinfo("Число в шестнадцатеричной системе", self.convert_base(self.iw.get(),16,2))
        if l==2:
            messagebox.showinfo("Число в десятичной системе", self.convert_base(self.iw.get(),10,2))
        if l==3:
            messagebox.showinfo("Число в восьмеричной системе", self.convert_base(sels.iw.get(),8,2))

    def convert_base(num, to_base=10, from_base=10):
        if isinstance(num, str):
            n = int(num, from_base)
        else:
            n = int(num)
        alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        if n < to_base:
            return alphabet[n]
        else:
            return convert_base(n // to_base, to_base) + alphabet[n % to_base]
```

код главного окна

```
from tkinter import *
from TranWin import TranWin
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys


def edit_click():
    r= TranWin()

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI на Python")
root.geometry("300x250")

main_menu = Menu()
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Translate", command=edit_click)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Exit")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Help")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="About")

root.config(menu=main_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Вкратце: подобные проблемы с привязанными переменными возникают тогда, когда дочерние окна создаются как объект `Tk()` вместо `Toplevel()`.

Я видоизменил ваш пример, убрав исходное главное окно:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

class TranWin:
    """description of class"""
    def __init__(self):  
        r = Tk()
        r.title("Translate")
        r.geometry("400x300")
        poetry = "Binary number"
        label2 = Label(r, text=poetry, justify=LEFT)
        label2.place(relx=.3, rely=.1)

        self.iw = StringVar()

        message_entry = Entry(r, textvariable=self.iw)
        message_entry.place(relx=.7, rely=.13, anchor="c")
        message_button = Button(r, text="Translate", command=self.show_message)
        message_button.place(relx=.7, rely=.3, anchor="c")

        self.ir = IntVar()

        Radiobutton(r, text='16', value=1, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=3, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(r, text='10', value=2, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=4, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(r, text='8', value=3, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=5, sticky=W) 
        r.mainloop()

    def show_message(self):
        l=self.ir.get()
        print(l)


TranWin()
```

При этом видно, что значение из ir отображается корректно. Отсюда предположение, что проблема как-то связана с тем, как вы создаете "дочернее" (на самом деле еще одно главное) окно.

Убираем в дочернем окне создание объекта `Tk()` (заменяем его на `Toplevel()`), убираем в дочернем окне `mainloop`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

class TranWin:
    """description of class"""
    def __init__(self):  
        r = Toplevel()
        r.title("Translate")
        r.geometry("400x300")
        poetry = "Binary number"
        label2 = Label(r, text=poetry, justify=LEFT)
        label2.place(relx=.3, rely=.1)

        self.iw = StringVar()

        message_entry = Entry(r, textvariable=self.iw)
        message_entry.place(relx=.7, rely=.13, anchor="c")
        message_button = Button(r, text="Translate", command=self.show_message)
        message_button.place(relx=.7, rely=.3, anchor="c")

        self.ir = IntVar()

        Radiobutton(r, text='16', value=1, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=3, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(r, text='10', value=2, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=4, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(r, text='8', value=3, variable=self.ir, padx=15, pady=10)\
            .grid(row=5, sticky=W) 

    def show_message(self):
        print(self.ir.get())
        print(self.iw.get())


def edit_click():
    r = TranWin()

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI на Python")
root.geometry("300x250")

main_menu = Menu()
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Translate", command=edit_click)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Exit")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Help")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="About")

root.config(menu=main_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

При нажатии на кнопку Translate видим в консоли правильные значения:

[image: Скриншот]