# RadioButton не передает значения переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radiobutton

Имею проблему. В рамках класса не передается значение переменной `selected`, указанное в свойстве  `value` класса `Radiobutton`.

В ходе переключения значение в свойстве `Radiobutton value` было задано как числа от `0` до `9` в зависимости от варианта. Но, при нажатии и выборе абсолютно любого `Radiobutton` оно как было заданным `1`, так и остается. Очевидно, что значение переменной `selected` из свойства `value` не подхватывается. Вывод этот делается на том основании, что значение переменной `Ttext`  в рамках процедуры  `GoToWork` не изменяется.

Бьюсь три часа и не вижу ошибки. Подскажите, буду очень благодарен!

вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
class OperationSwitch():
    def GoToWork(self):
        Ttext="ничего не выбрано"
        if self.selected.get()==1:
            Ttext="Свободная раздача трубчатой заготовки"
            print(self.selected.get())
        elif self.selected.get()==2:
            Ttext='Формовка переходников'
        elif self.selected.get()==3:
            Ttext='Формовка рифтов'
        elif self.selected.get()==4:
            Ttext = 'Разделительные операции на трубах'
        elif self.selected.get()==5:
            Ttext = "Пробивка отверстий в плоских заготовках"
        elif self.selected.get()==6:
            Ttext='Гибка бортов'
        elif self.selected.get()==7:
            Ttext='Формовка плоских заготовок'
        elif self.selected.get()==8:
            Ttext='Калибровка на отжим'
        elif self.selected.get()==9:
            Ttext ='Калибровка на раздачу'
        print(Ttext)
        print(self.selected.get())

    def GUI (self):
        self.OperationSwitch = Tk()
        self.OperationSwitch.geometry('500x300')  # геометрия окна
        self.OperationSwitch.title("Выбор операции")  # название окна
        lbl = Label(self.OperationSwitch, text="Выберите необходимую операцию:", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.selected = IntVar()
        self.selected.set(1)
        rad1 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Свободная раздача трубчатой заготовки', variable=self.selected, value=int(1))
        rad2 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Формовка переходников', variable=self.selected,value=int(2))
        rad3 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Формовка рифтов', variable=self.selected, value=3)
        rad4 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Разделительные операции на трубах', variable=self.selected,value=4)
        rad5 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Пробивка отверстий в плоских заготовках', variable=self.selected,value=5)
        rad6 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Гибка бортов', variable=self.selected, value=6)
        rad7 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Формовка плоских заготовок', variable=self.selected,value=7)
        rad8 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Калибровка на отжим', variable=self.selected,value=8)
        rad9 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Калибровка на раздачу', variable=self.selected,value=9)
        print(self.selected.get())
        rad1.place(x=10, y=40)
        rad2.place(x=10, y=60)
        rad3.place(x=10, y=80)
        rad4.place(x=10, y=100)
        rad5.place(x=10, y=120)
        rad6.place(x=10, y=140)
        rad7.place(x=10, y=160)
        rad8.place(x=10, y=180)
        rad9.place(x=10, y=200)
        btn = Button(self.OperationSwitch, text="Закрыть окно", bg="red", fg="black", command=self.CloseWindow)
        btn.place(x=10, y=250)
        btn = Button(self.OperationSwitch, text="Внести данные", bg="green", fg="black", command=self.GoToWork)
        btn.place(x=300, y=250)
        self.OperationSwitch.mainloop()
    def __init__(self):
        self.GUI()


    def CloseWindow(self): self.OperationSwitch.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня ваш пример работает правильно

```
from tkinter import *

class OperationSwitch():
    def __init__(self):
        self.GUI()

    def GoToWork(self):
        Ttext="ничего не выбрано"
        if self.selected.get()==1:
            Ttext="Свободная раздача трубчатой заготовки"
            print(self.selected.get())
        elif self.selected.get()==2:
            Ttext='Формовка переходников'
        elif self.selected.get()==3:
            Ttext='Формовка рифтов'
        elif self.selected.get()==4:
            Ttext = 'Разделительные операции на трубах'
        elif self.selected.get()==5:
            Ttext = "Пробивка отверстий в плоских заготовках"
        elif self.selected.get()==6:
            Ttext='Гибка бортов'
        elif self.selected.get()==7:
            Ttext='Формовка плоских заготовок'
        elif self.selected.get()==8:
            Ttext='Калибровка на отжим'
        elif self.selected.get()==9:
            Ttext ='Калибровка на раздачу'
        print(Ttext)
        print(self.selected.get())

    def GUI (self):
        self.OperationSwitch = Tk()
        self.OperationSwitch.geometry('500x300')      # геометрия окна
        self.OperationSwitch.title("Выбор операции")  # название окна
        lbl = Label(self.OperationSwitch, text="Выберите необходимую операцию:", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
        lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.selected = IntVar()
        self.selected.set(1)
        rad1 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Свободная раздача трубчатой заготовки', variable=self.selected, value=int(1))
        rad2 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Формовка переходников', variable=self.selected,value=int(2))
        rad3 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Формовка рифтов', variable=self.selected, value=3)
        rad4 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Разделительные операции на трубах', variable=self.selected,value=4)
        rad5 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Пробивка отверстий в плоских заготовках', variable=self.selected,value=5)
        rad6 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Гибка бортов', variable=self.selected, value=6)
        rad7 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Формовка плоских заготовок', variable=self.selected,value=7)
        rad8 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Калибровка на отжим', variable=self.selected,value=8)
        rad9 = Radiobutton(self.OperationSwitch, text='Калибровка на раздачу', variable=self.selected,value=9)
        print(self.selected.get())
        rad1.place(x=10, y=40)
        rad2.place(x=10, y=60)
        rad3.place(x=10, y=80)
        rad4.place(x=10, y=100)
        rad5.place(x=10, y=120)
        rad6.place(x=10, y=140)
        rad7.place(x=10, y=160)
        rad8.place(x=10, y=180)
        rad9.place(x=10, y=200)
        btn = Button(self.OperationSwitch, text="Закрыть окно", bg="red", fg="black", command=self.CloseWindow)
        btn.place(x=10, y=250)
        btn = Button(self.OperationSwitch, text="Внести данные", bg="green", fg="black", command=self.GoToWork)
        btn.place(x=300, y=250)
        self.OperationSwitch.mainloop()

    def CloseWindow(self): 
        self.OperationSwitch.destroy() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = OperationSwitch()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень интересно...... в чем тогда может быть причина того, что у меня значение не меняется? Я использую PyCharm на Ubuntu. Вызываю данный класс из другого класса.... что тут может быть? И может ли быть что-то.

Comment: @ValeriyM.Raznomazov, если у вас другой класс тоже создается как объект Tk, то в этом и есть проблема. Только основное окно должно создаваться как Tk, все дочерние - как Toplevel

Comment: Да, действительно. Если делать ScratchFile и запискать его вне проекта, он работает. Не работает он в составе проекта. Очевидно, то где-то конфликт переменных или каких-то идентификаторов.

Comment: @ValeriyM.Raznomazov, вот вопрос с похожей проблемой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/929706/1365

Comment: Спасибо! убил предыдущий класс перед выводом данного и все заработало. Спасибо огромное, вы очень помогли.